# Populate function return value into <input> element

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, onclick

I am writing a chat page for my site. I have successfully managed to `getmyFunction()` to ask the user for their name to simply say welcome 'username'. The problem is that I would like to also use the same name within a name input box for the chat itself, rather than the user having to input their name every single time they wish to write a message. i have used `onclick=` to prompt the user for their name but I cannot get it to display that name within the name box.

```
<form action='submit.php' method='post' name='form'>

Your name:<br><p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
}
}
</script>
Your Name: <br>
<input type='text' name='name' size='20' onclick='myFunction()'><br>

Your message:<br>

<textarea name='message' cols='40' rows='2'></textarea><br>
```

Edit: I have since discovered that whilst the javascript code is in submit.php, submit.php does not display at all :/

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle for demonstration?
Edit: also consider adding `return false;` at the end of the myFunction() to prevent form submit

Comment: I have not used JSFiddle before but i will get the code up there asap.

Comment: JSFiddle is confusing the hell out of me! I have four seperate .php files that call on one another the actual page users will view is simply 2 `<iframe>`'s and i dont understand the splitting up of all my code into js fiddle, sorry

Comment: i am also using MySQL to store chat and display back to users so how would this work on JSFiddle if the database isnt available..

Comment: i didn't meant to add whole application, i just meant the problematic part. JSFiddle is only to test/show client-side parts

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify that what happens, what should happen, and where do you want it to happen. From what you've told, I take it you want to change the input's value to the name the user entered through the prompt dialog. In this case, you could do:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
        if (person) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
            document.getElementById("name").value = person;
        }
    }
</script>
```

By the way, this was not part of the question, but when you have an input field for entering a username, asking it through a prompt dialog just doesn't make sense. You could ask the user to enter it through the input field, and whenever it's changed (`onchanged` property of the `<input>` element), you handle it with your script.

Comment: yes that is what i wished to do, i have added your code example, but it does nothing different. Also my chat page refreshes every 2 seconds and once refreshed the name entered vanishes? And my apologies for not be precise in my question, i also should have said i am very much a beginner with web development so frankly dont know the `onchanged` propeety as yet

Comment: Refreshing a page so many times is considered a bad practice, because it puts a huge load on your server, so when several users are connected, this becomes a critical problem, and it's also uncomfortable for the user. You should try AJAX, which allows for asynchronous communication between server and client, that means, without the need of reloading the page.